# Access local host from remote server-side

Tags: database, docker, server, localhost, remote-access

I didn't find anything clear on that subject so I would prefer to ask before deploying my app on a remote server.

I would like my meteor web app to interact with influx & mongo databases running locally on the user's computer (this machine being a docker container, actually), even if the app is running on a remote server. But it seems that connecting to a given url is not possible inside the client-side script (it send me an error when I do new InfluxDB(...), or MongoClient.connect(...).

It works fine if the connexion is made from the server side, but for now my app is only running locally for development, so it's not surprising. Will it still be possible when the app is deployed on a remote server? Otherwise, is there a simple solution to reach these local machines ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a remote server to access your local computer, you can't user localhost, you need to have a dedicated public internet ip, or a dyndns pointing to your public ip, and connect to that address.

You will also will have to open a whole in your internet facing router to forward the ports to the intranet ip address of your computer.

And also open a whole in your firewall (windows / linux) for those connections to pass through and reach Mongo or InFluxDb.

Personally I don't rcomend doing this due to the security implications and I really don't see any benefit of doing something like this.

Comment: I agree. Sounds quite clumsy to proceed like that. The problem is that I wanted to make local copies of remote databases using javascript API and for that I need to connect to the local ones. But I find some issues when trying to connect to localhost in the client side script. However, in this situation, the app is supposed to run both on the remote server and locally on the user's computer (I want to transfer data from the server to the computer to enable offline use), so I think I'll try to build these copies on the server, then download it with the local version of the app.

Comment: You can also explore doing the backup to dropbox

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want to use your server-side code to manipulate the Mongo database in the client? If so, please check:

1. does the client-side machine has the Mongo database?
2. is the database running?
3. does the database open its port?
4. is your connection configuration is correct?

It's better to show your code so that I can check whether there is any issue.

Comment: This is indeed what I tried to do, because it doesn't work when I run the following command, for example, from the client side: const localMongo = Mongo.MongoClient.connect("mongodb://root:root@192.168.99.100:27017/mongodb");   I get the error TypeError: net.createConnection is not a function. Seems that this function cannot run in the browser and must be put in the server-side scripts.

Comment: The code cannot run in your client(browser).
If you want to manipulate the data from your client(browser), put the code to the server-side, and wrap it with a function, let's say changeData(). If you want to change data in mongo, just call this function with Metear.call('changeData') from your client (browser), this might solve your issue.